# Unable to create partitions dynamically in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create partitions on my table dynamically whenever a new entry is about to insert. I have written a trigger that checks if necessary partition is there if not it will create one and performs insert on that partition. Each partition is named config_YYYY-MM-DD(partition for each day) format.  Here's the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_trigger_config()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    partition_name TEXT;
BEGIN
    -- Generate the partition name based on the event_date of the new row
    partition_name := 'config_' || NEW.date::TEXT;

    -- Check if the partition already exists
    IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name = partition_name
) THEN
    -- Create the new partition
    EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I PARTITION OF config FOR VALUES FROM (%L) TO (%L)', partition_name, NEW.date, (NEW.date + interval '1 day')::text);
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I DISABLE TRIGGER ALL', partition_name); -- necessary to avoid recursion as the same triggers are applied to partitions
END IF;

    -- Insert the new row into the appropriate partition
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I VALUES ($1.*)', partition_name) USING NEW;

    -- Return the new row
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE or replace TRIGGER partition_trigger_config
BEFORE INSERT ON config
FOR EACH row
EXECUTE FUNCTION create_partition_trigger_config();
```

I am getting following error:
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [ERROR: no partition of relation "config" found for row
Detail: Partition key of the failing row contains (date) = (2024-03-15).] [insert into config (date,game_id,json_data,timestamp,type,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into config (date,game_id,json_data,timestamp,type,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)]; constraint [null].

It is checking the valid partition key before the trigger which will create a valid partition?
How to solve this.

Comment: From [5.11. Table Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-LIMITATIONS): *BEFORE ROW triggers on INSERT cannot change which partition is the final destination for a new row.* Even without this warning, I wouldn't mix that sort of DLL into my DML if I were you.